# Django JWT - Add Custom Field to User

Tags: json, django, rest, jwt, fetch

I want to add a custom field to JWT User Model like biography and fetch with API. I couldn't handle with it, i'm so confused. I'm getting this error "**django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Field name `bio` is not valid for model `User`.**"

**My models.py as below:**

```
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from rest_framework_jwt.serializers import User
from tinymce.models import HTMLField



class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
```

**Views.py**

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, status, permissions
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated, AllowAny
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.decorators import action, api_view
from .serializers import UserSerializer, UserSerializerWithToken


@api_view(['GET'])
def current_user(request):
    """
    Determine the current user by their token, and return their data
    """

    serializer = UserSerializer(request.user)
    return Response(serializer.data)


class UserList(APIView):
    """
    Create a new user. It's called 'UserList' because normally we'd have a get
    method here too, for retrieving a list of all User objects.
    """

    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = UserSerializerWithToken(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**Serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework_jwt.serializers import User

from .models import Content, Rating
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework_jwt.settings import api_settings


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username',)


class UserSerializerWithToken(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    token = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    def get_token(self, obj):
        jwt_payload_handler = api_settings.JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER
        jwt_encode_handler = api_settings.JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER

        payload = jwt_payload_handler(obj)
        token = jwt_encode_handler(payload)
        return token

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        if password is not None:
            instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save()
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('token', 'username', 'password', 'bio')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

`from rest_framework_jwt.serializers import User`

to

`from django.contrib.auth.models import User`

Comment: Also Replace TextField with CharField. It may cause a problem because serializer don't have TextField.

Answer (score -1):

I also faced the same problem. When I was building authentication (sign in) page. first we must build new database and then we should connect with these new database with our code and do some regular changes in superuser or (if custom user exist) in our apps model after do all regular changes. You must run `py manage.py makmigrations` after that `py manage.py migrate`.

After that all things we check by register with the help of postman (or any API request checking application). If we do all changes perfect then that registration is become successful other wise it will show something errors.

Here one question is also arises: What happens with `is_admin`?

If you do all above things then after that we do register successfully then we show our data on database. So here with the help of this data of the database we can also make a new admin of our admin panel.

How? Then I was used MySQL with XAMPP. So in the XAMPP local server I made a new admin. We can changes in admin local host. So we can also make an admin to user from here.